# C++ check TCP port

Tags: c++

I have written a program in `C++` and i need to check if a TCP port is truely empty.

This is the function :

```
int checkport(char* host, char* port, int timeout)
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    int result = 0;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(atoi(port));
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);
    fd_set fdset;
    struct timeval tv;
    fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    int connect_result = connect(sock,(struct sockaddr*)(&sin),sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(sock, &fdset);
    tv.tv_sec = timeout;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    int select_result = select(sock + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv);

    // printf("connect = [%d] | select = [%d]\n",connect_result,select_result);

    if(select_result == 1)
    {
        int so_error;
        socklen_t len = sizeof so_error;
        getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &len);

        // printf("so_error = [%d] \n",so_error);

        if(so_error == 0)
        {
            //Is connected
            if(hitdebug >= 4) puts("CONNECTED");
            if(hitdebug >= 2) printf("[%s:%s] OPEN\n",host,port);

            result = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(hitdebug >= 4) puts("CONNECT_ERROR_1");

            result = 0;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(hitdebug >= 4) puts("CONNECT_ERROR_2");

        result = 0;
    }

    close(sock);

    return result;
}
```

The problem is that is detecting only LISTEN port, i want a port to be 100% true and even detect ESTABLISHED, TIME_WAIT, etc ...

Output :

```
connect = [-1] | select = [1]
so_error = [111]
50983 TEST=[0]
tcp        0      0 1.2.3.4:50983       4.4.4.4:22       ESTABLISHED


connect = [-1] | select = [1]
so_error = [111]
43343 TEST=[0]
tcp        0      0 1.2.3.4:43343       4.4.4.4:22       ESTABLISHED


connect = [-1] | select = [1]
so_error = [0]
64000 TEST=[1]
tcp        0      0 1.2.3.4:64000       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 1.2.3.4:47669       1.2.3.4:64000       TIME_WAIT


connect = [-1] | select = [1]
so_error = [111]
54674 TEST=[0]


connect = [-1] | select = [1]
so_error = [111]
54665 TEST=[0]
```

For me an empty port is when i do a `netstat -an | grep 12345 | wc -l` and i see 0, not even a FIN_WAIT

How can i accomplish that?

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to specify what OS you're on, C++ doesn't yet have anything network related that is in the standard (which is crazy). And despite the similarities between the Unix like families, there is still quite some differences

Comment: Just try to `bind` the port for listening - if it fails (with `SO_REUSEADDR` off, which is the default), then the socket is either in active use or in one of the WAIT states.

Comment: Why don't you parse the netstat output ?

Comment: What's your reason for doing this?  As n.m. states there will be race conditions.

Comment: race conditions ... your're right, i have no choice, i want to do a proxy checker from a list

Comment: What does that mean? What is the proxy you're starting, and how do you run it? Can it inherit a bound socket from your existing process?

Answer (score 16):

```
if (the_port_is_free(port_number)) {
   /* is the port free at this point? */
}
```

The correct answer is "who knows?"  Sure, it *was* free a nanosecond ago when the control was somewhere in the function `the_port_is_free`, but is it free *now*? There are many other processes around, perhaps one of them took the port half a nanosecond ago?

This is called a race condition. Every programmer should understand the concept.

It is precisely because of this problem `the_port_is_free` is not provided by your OS: it only would give you false expectations, not correct answers. You cannot know whether the port is free now and, more importantly, will be free in a nanosecond when you decide to bind it. The only way to bind the port is to go ahead and try binding it.

This approach applies to a whole bunch of situations. Whenever there's a shared resource of any kind, there's usually no function that tells you if it's OK to grab it. The only way to get it is to go ahead and try.

Comment: i am happy with `will be free in a nanosecond when` , i understand your point of view, i am trying to do a proxy checker, my problem is that the program is not detecting `ESTABLISHED` , `WAIT` , `FIN_WAIT`, understand me? a nanosecond less or more is not an issue for me

Comment: @Damian No, absolutely don't understand you. Why do you need this? What will you do with the answer?

Comment: i understand the concept of racing conition, i just need to make my function detecting `ESTAB` , `WAIT` , `FIN_WAIT`, that's all. Now it is detectng only `LISTENING`

Comment: Why do you need to detect all these states? What would you do with the detectedd states? Why can't you just `open_proxy` and see if it fails?

Comment: i have to check port it before opening, really need this, is complicated to explain why, really need it like that

Answer (score 8):

Just try to `bind` the port for listening - if it fails (with `SO_REUSEADDR` off, which is the default), then the socket is either in active use or in one of the WAIT states.

Comment: and it will detect ESTAB as well ?

Comment: and after i `bind()`, how can i un-bind and free the port ASAP so i can open a proxy on it?

Comment: If the `bind` succeeds, you already bound the port and know it _was_ free, which is what you said you wanted to do. If you close and re-bind the port, there's an unavoidable race condition. The only thing you can safely do with your bound port is use it directly. What is this proxy, and why can't you just let _it_ do the `bind` and see if it fails?

Comment: `an unavoidable race condition` ?? look as this code : https://pastebin.com/Q0hRYvW0 how can thys be a race condition? everything is sync, the `.close()` happens then `open_proxy()`, understand me?

Comment: Because ports are _shared between all processes on the machine_. So _some other process_ can bind the port between you closing it and starting the proxy. Unless your proxy is in-process code, and you can avoid closing the bound socket in the first place, which is why I asked to what the proxy is. Understand me?

Comment: It is a SOCKS5 proxy, the thing is that netstat.c knows to show me ESTABLISHED , WAIT , FIN_WAIT, how can i do the same? maybe to look into theirs code?

Comment: That _will not help_. The race condition is _inherent_. The _only_ way to safely confirm that a socket is free for use by some process (I assume it's  a process rather than a library, although you _still_ haven't answered that bit) is for **that** process to successfully bind the socket and then start using it. That's it. Releasing the socket allows it to be stolen again. Just running netstat, or reproducing it, allows the socket to be stolen between your check and the proxy starting.

Comment: i knew that `netstat` just read, i don't understand how can `netstat` stole something, and "allows the socket to be stolen between your check and the proxy starting" happens in max 100ms, no need to worry, just need to detect ESTAB, WAIT, FIN_WAIT, i will try the `bind()` ... but i don't know what is the command to `unbind(), close()`, i will search tutorials

Comment: _sigh_, I didn't say that netstat stole anything. I said that some _other_ process can take the socket between netstat telling you its free, and your proxy trying to use it. This probably won't happen often, and it will seem to work fine in initial testing, and then it will eventually break. And, it won't be fixable _at all_ with your current approach, as a matter of principle. Anyway, to unbind a bound socket, just close it. You know there are actual references for this stuff, right? A combination of getting started tutorials and questions here isn't likely to be ideal.

Comment: `I said that some other process can take the socket between netstat telling you its free, and your proxy trying to use it` -> you are right and i am all right with this , i haven't worked a lot with sockets in c++, but thank you for your help. the idea of checking if the proxy opened on port XXXXX it is plausible, because the library i am using, indeed tells something if the proxy opened, but it tells this in another `fork()`, so i must do something to make communication between 2 processes, witch i don't know ...